# How to download multiple file part simultaneously?

Tags: python, sockets

I am developing a download accelerator in python and I want to spedd up download but when I get the header response of some server I don't have Content-length field and I don't know how to slice the download to launch it on many sockets (I think I will use select)
Here is my code

```
def parse_chunk(chunk: bytes, current_chunk_length_remaining: int) -> tuple[bytes, int, bytes]:
    """"
        this function receive a chunk and parse it following rules of RFC 2616 section 3.6.1
        return
            real_data | current_chunk: bytes
            chunk_length_remaining: int
            remaining_data: bytes
        link for RFC 2616 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1
    """
    # This is the first chunk or the previous chunk ended with the previous packet received
    if current_chunk_length_remaining == 0:
        chunk_header, chunk_body = chunk.split(b'\r\n', 1)
        try:
            response_length, chunk_extension = chunk_header.split(b';')
        except ValueError:
            response_length = chunk_header.split(b';')[0]
            chunk_extension = b''
        #  response_length.decode('utf-8')
        response_length = int(response_length, base=16)  # convert from HEX to int
        real_data = chunk_body[:response_length]
        remaining_data = chunk_body[response_length:]
        if len(real_data) < response_length:  # This means that the chunk is not complete
            chunk_length_remaining = response_length - len(chunk_body)
        else:  # They are equals
            chunk_length_remaining = 0
        return real_data, chunk_length_remaining, remaining_data
    # The previous packet received didn't have the current chunk in totality
    elif current_chunk_length_remaining > 0:
        current_chunk = chunk[:current_chunk_length_remaining]
        remaining_data = chunk[current_chunk_length_remaining:]
        if len(current_chunk) < current_chunk_length_remaining:  # This means that the chunk is not complete
            chunk_length_remaining = current_chunk_length_remaining - len(current_chunk)
        else:  # They are equals
            chunk_length_remaining = 0
        return current_chunk, chunk_length_remaining, remaining_data
```

```
def parse_http_get_response(server_interface: socket, link: str, target_host: str, user_agent: str) \
        -> tuple[bytes, bytes]:
    request = "GET /" + link + \
              " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{}\r\nUser-Agent: {}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n".format(target_host, user_agent)
    server_interface.send(request.encode('utf-8'))
    data = server_interface.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    http_headers, response_body = data.split(b'\r\n\r\n', 1)
    return http_headers, response_body
```

```
def download_chunk_data(server_interface: socket, path_to_file: str, link: str, target_host: str,
                        user_agent: str):
    _, response_body = parse_http_get_response(server_interface, link, target_host, user_agent)
    real_data, chunk_length_remaining, remaining_data = parse_chunk(response_body, 0)
    is_start = True
    with open(path_to_file, "wb") as res:
        is_file_end = False
        end_of_file = re.compile(b'\r\n0\r\n\r\n')
        data = real_data
        while True:
            if not is_start:
                real_data, chunk_length_remaining, remaining_data = parse_chunk(data, chunk_length_remaining)
                tmp = b''
                if len(remaining_data) == 0:
                    tmp = real_data
                if end_of_file.match(remaining_data):
                    tmp = real_data
                    is_file_end = True
                while chunk_length_remaining != 0 and len(remaining_data) != 0:
                    tmp += real_data
                    real_data, chunk_length_remaining, remaining_data = \
                        parse_chunk(remaining_data, chunk_length_remaining)
                data = tmp
            res.write(data)
            if not data or is_file_end:
                server_interface.close()
                break
            data = server_interface.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            is_start = False

targetHost = "www.livrespourtous.com"
targetPort = 80
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 " \
             "Safari/537.36 "
testLink = "http://www.livrespourtous.com/e-books/detail/Le-PDF-gratuit-et-libre/onecat/0.html"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client:
    client.connect((targetHost, targetPort))
    download_chunk_data(client, "response.html", testLink, targetHost, userAgent)
```

I use download_chunk_data function to download if the Transfert Type is Chunked

Answer (score 1):

> but when I get the header response of some server I don't have Content-length field

This particular server uses chunked transfer encoding. The length is not known up-front with this, that's why it is impossible to figure out how to split the response. This is typically the case with dynamically generated files.

But this isn't actually relevant in this case at all, because the server does not support ranges anyway (at least for this URL), i.e there is no `Accept-Ranges` header in the response. This means every request will start from the beginning of the data, no way to instruct the server otherwise.

Comment: I will try to change the URL and I will share my issues. Thanks.